# Connect to Outlook from Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, outlook, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

we have a python Cloud Function running in GCP that retrieves attachments from an outlook account. Until now we have been using Basic Authentication with IMAP to connect, but as Basic Auth will be deprecated during the second half of this year we want to upgrade it to use Modern Auth.
We have tried following this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth

We registered the application in Azure and generated a secret. In permissions we added Microsoft Grapth:
IMAP.AccessAsUser.All.

We are able to create the access token but then when we try to authenticate the authentication fails. This is our code:

```
import logging
import adal
import requests
import base64
import imaplib

def main():
        context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority)
    
        # Use this for Client Credentials
        token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(RESOURCE,client_id,client_secret)
        print(token['accessToken'])
    
    
    
        auth_string = GenerateOAuth2String(my_email, token['accessToken'], base64_encode=False)
        print(auth_string)
        TestImapAuthentication(my_email, auth_string)
    
    
    def TestImapAuthentication(user, auth_string):


      imap_conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('outlook.office365.com')
      imap_conn.debug = 4
      imap_conn.authenticate('XOAUTH2', lambda x: auth_string)
      imap_conn.select('INBOX')
    
    
    def GenerateOAuth2String(username, access_token, base64_encode=True):
    
      auth_string = 'user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1' % (username, access_token)
      if base64_encode:
        auth_string = base64.b64encode(auth_string)
      return auth_string
```

And this is the error we receive:

```
  04:58.56 > b'DJCP1 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2'
  04:58.65 < b'+ '
  04:58.65 write literal size 2080
  04:59.88 < b'DJCP1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.'
  04:59.88 NO response: b'AUTHENTICATE failed.'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "token_test.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "token_test.py", line 27, in main
    TestImapAuthentication(my_email, auth_string)
  File "token_test.py", line 34, in TestImapAuthentication
    imap_conn.authenticate('XOAUTH2', lambda x: auth_string)
  File "C:\Users\naia\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\imaplib.py", line 430, in authenticate
    raise self.error(dat[-1].decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
imaplib.error: AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

Any idea why the authentication is failing?

```
Thank you for your help in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and solved it by changing the resource/scope uri from:
https://graph.microsoft.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All
to
https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#get-an-access-token

**Edit after review:**

To clarify I am making an assumption since the question doesn't include what the `RESOURCE` variable is set to. My assumption is:

```
RESOURCE = "https://graph.microsoft.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All"
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(RESOURCE,client_id,client_secret)
```

My suggested answer, if my assumption is correct, is to change `RESOURCE` to:

```
RESOURCE = "https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All"
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(RESOURCE,client_id,client_secret)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31789799)

Comment: @EmiOB I respectfully disagree with your review. I did include the essential part of what needed to be changed. I have added to my answer to be more clear.

Comment: Link only answers  are unhelpful as links can break, and then the answer becomes unhelpful. Your edit now includes the key information from the links in the answer, so it is better for future use :)